# Need a Linux script to schedule a job without using Cron or at

Tags: scripting, rhel, cron

For an older Redhat Linux OS, having trouble getting a job to run from Cron, but it works fine from my user account / command line.

Seems to have something to do with Cron using a different shell from my user.

Is there a way to have a script running in the background using my user account that schedules 1 or more jobs at given times?

Cron entry:

```
00      08      *       *       *       DBPATH='/usr2/customer/actr/data/409';export DBPATH;/usr2/customer/actr/systems/adsnew/scripts/rb3pamrx8.sh 'lp -d macaplp01 -s -oL' 'Y' '409' 'today+1' '1' 'DEV'
```

Comment: Most crons can set the SHELL to run as (or work around it with a wrapper); shall we try to solve that problem, or avoid cron altogether?

Comment: I added the Cron entry at bottom

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in a script and schedule the script.  If it's longer than a single command, or uses anything "fancy", just put it in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

DBPATH='/usr2/customer/actr/data/409'
export DBPATH

/usr2/customer/actr/systems/adsnew/scripts/rb3pamrx8.sh \
    'lp -d macaplp01 -s -oL' \
    'Y' '409' 'today+1' \
    '1' 'DEV'
```

This makes it more readable and since it's not hidden away in a crontab somewhere, you may change it without having to modify the crontab entry. It also makes it possible to add control structures and logic if needs be, without having to try to do it all in one line.

In short: It separates the action (the script) from the schedule.

The crontab entry may be

```
0 8 * * * /usr2/customer/actr/cronscripts/theprintjob.sh
```

or something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of my user's crontab:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/noc
LOGNAME=jessebutryn
USER=jessebutryn
HOME=/Users/jessebutryn
#
0 12 * * * /Users/jessebutryn/Documents/scripts/shell/tools/mantasync.sh
0,15,30,45 * * * * /Users/jessebutryn/Documents/scripts/shell/tools/ntoolssync.sh
```

If you don't want to set variables for your entire cron tab but have a job that needs to run with your user's environment you can usually just source your bash profile, similar to this:

```
0 2,6,10,14,18,22 * * * . /root/.bash_profile ; /opt/local/bin/fraudchk
```

Comment: How do I access my cron settings?

Comment: Type `crontab -e`

Comment: I don't have SHELL, PATH,etc at the top when I go into crontab, could that be the problem?

Comment: I wouldn't quite call it the problem but it may be the solution...Yes, adding whatever variables are needed by your scripts to your crontab may solve your issue.

Comment: That would also affect other jobs scheduled in the crontab though.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Agreed.  That's why I didn't want to say it was a "problem", and I gave the alternative solution of sourcing the bash profile for the individual job that needs it.  There is a reason cron uses a different environment.

Comment: How do I view my user settings to find out what to put in Cron?

Comment: Type the `env` command.

Comment: Would I need to stop and restart my Cron to have it pickup the new settings?

Comment: No it should all be parsed every time a scheduled job runs.  You can also setup a scheduled job to run the `env` command from cron and dump it into a file and then you can compare cron's environment to your user and likely narrow down exactly what is missing.

Comment: What if I copy and pasted my entire env into the top of the cron, would that mess anything up?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that at all.